# Logarithmic Spiral - Is Point on Spiral (cartesian coordinates

Tags: c#

Lets Say I have a 3d Cartesian grid. Lets also assume that there are one or more log spirals emanating from the origin on the horizontal plane.

If I then have a point in the grid I want to test if that point is in one of the spirals. I acutally want to test if it within a certain range of the spirals but determining if it is on the point is a good start.

So I guess the question has a couple parts.

1. How to generate the arms from parameters (direction, tightness)
2. How to tell if a point in the grid is in one of the spiral arms

Any ideas? I have been googling all day and don't feel I am any closer to a solution than when I started.

Here is a bit more information that might help:

I don't actually need to render the spirals. I want to set the pitch and rotation and then pass a point to a method that can tell me if the point I passed is within the spiral (within a given range of any point on the spiral). Based on the value returned (true or false) my program will make a decision on whether or not something exists at the point in space.

1. How to parametrically define the log spirals (pitch and rotation and ??)
2. Test if a point (x, y, z) is withing a given range of any point on the spiral.

Note: Both of the above would be just on the horizontal plane

Comment: Is this done graphically, so someone can click on a 3D image and you want to see if it falls on a spiral? Or, do you just have a matrix of points and someone gives you coordinates?  Basically, how do you display it and how does someone give the coordinates?

Comment: Eventually it will be graphical but for now I have a method that wants to decide if something exists at a certain point in a cartesian grid. Whether or not that point is on or near a log spiral on the horizontal plane is a part of that decision. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep those things in mind. Appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 2):

These are two functions defining an anti-clockwise spiral:

```
PolarPlot[{

  Exp[(t + 10)/100],
  Exp[t/100]},

 {t, 0, 100 Pi}]
```

Output:

[image]

These are two functions defining a clockwise spiral:

```
PolarPlot[{

 - Exp[(t + 10)/100],
 - Exp[t/100]},

 {t, 0, 100 Pi}]
```

Output:

[image]

**Cartesian coordinates**

The conversion Cartesian <-> Polar is

```
  (1)  Ro = Sqrt[x^2+y^2] 
        t = ArcTan[y/x]

  (2)  x  = Ro Cos[t]
       y  = Ro Sin[t]
```

So, If you have a point in Cartesian Coords (x,y) you transform it to your equivalent polar coordinates using (1). Then  you use the forula for the spiral function (any of the four mentinoned above the plots, or similar ones) putting in there the value for t, and obtaining Ro. The last step is to compare this Ro with the one we got from the coordinates converion. If they are equal, the point is on the spiral.

**Edit** Answering your comment

For a Log spiral is almost the same, but with multiple spirals you need to take care of the logs not going to negative values. That's why I used exponentials ...

Example:

```
PolarPlot[{

  Log[t],
  If[t > 3, Log[ t - 2], 0],
  If[t > 5, Log[ t - 4], 0]

}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but you can reverse the log function (or "any" other for that matter).
Say you have ln A = B, to get A from B you do e^B = A.

So you get your point and pass it as B, you'll get A. Then you just need to check if that A (with a certain +- range) is in the values you first passed on to ln to generate the spiral.

I think this might work...

Comment: I am not good with math notation at all. Could you explain the above in a code or psuedo code snippet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will need to know some mathematics notation anyway - this is a good read about the logarithmic sprial.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral

we will only need the top 4 equations.

For your question 1 
- to control the tightness, you tune the parameter 'a' as in the wiki page.
- to control the direction, you offset theta by a certain amount.

For your question 2

In floating point arithmetic, you will never get absolute precision, which mean there will be no point falling exactly on the sprial. On the screen, however, you will know which pixel get rendered, and you can test whether you are hitting a point that is rendered.

To render a curve, you usually render it as a sequence of line segments, short enough so that overall it looks like a curve. If you want to know whether a point lies within certain distance from the spiral, you can render the curve (on a off-screen buffer if you wish) by having thicker lines.

Answer (score 0):

here a C++ code drawing any spiral passing where the mouse here
(sorry for my English)

```
int cx = pWin->vue.right / 2;
int cy = pWin->vue.bottom / 2;


double theta_mouse = atan2((double)(pWin->y_mouse - cy),(double)(pWin->x_mouse - cx));
double square_d_mouse = (double)(pWin->y_mouse - cy)*(double)(pWin->y_mouse - cy)+
                        (double)(pWin->x_mouse - cx)*(double)(pWin->x_mouse - cx);
double d_mouse = sqrt(square_d_mouse);
double theta_t = log( d_mouse / 3.0 ) / log( 1.19 );
int x = cx + (3 * cos(theta_mouse)); 
int y = cy + (3 * sin(theta_mouse));

MoveToEx(hdc,x,y,NULL);
for(double theta=0.0;theta < PI2*5.0;theta+=0.1)
{
    double d = pow( 1.19 , theta ) * 3.0;

    x = cx + (d * cos(theta-theta_t+theta_mouse)); 
    y = cy + (d * sin(theta-theta_t+theta_mouse));

    LineTo(hdc,x,y);
}
```

Ok now the parameter of spiral is 1.19 (slope) and 3.0 (radius at center)
Just compare the points where theta is a mutiple of 2 PI = PI2 = 6,283185307179586476925286766559
if any points is near of a non rotated spiral like

```
x = cx + (d * cos(theta)); 
y = cy + (d * sin(theta));
```

then your mouse is ON the spiral... I searched this tonight and i googled your past question