# Following 3D Spiral Path

Tags: spiral, helix

I would like to produce a realistic 3D demonstration of a ball rolling down a Conical Helix path. The reference that has helped me get close to a solution can be found [here](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/spiral.htm). [I am creating my solution in Actionscript 3, using Stage3D, but would be happy to have any suggested coding solutions in other languages, using other 3D frameworks, with which you may be more familiar.]

As I entered the title for my posting, the system pointed me to a wealth of "Questions that may already have your answer", and that was helpful, and I did check each of them out. Without wanting to hijack an existing thread, I should say that [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289452/logarithmic-spiral-is-point-on-spiral-cartesian-coordinates)includes a good deal of very helpful commentary about the general subject, but does not get to the specific challenges I have been unable to resolve.

Using the cited reference, I am happy with this code snippet that traces the path I would like the ball to follow. [***N.B.*** My reference, and most other math-based references, treat Z as being up-down; my usage, however, is the more usual 3D graphics of Y for up-down.]

This code is executed for each frame.

```
ft += 0.01; // Where ft is a global Number.
var n:Number = Math.pow (0.5, (0.15 * ft));
// Where s is a constant used to scale the overall path.
obj.moveTo (
    (s * n * Math.cos (2.0 * ft)),
    (s * n),
    (s * n * Math.sin (2.0 * ft))
    );
```

The ball follows a nice path, and owing to the lighting and other shader code, a very decent effect is viewed in the scene.

What is not good about my current implementation is that the ball does not appear to be rolling along that path as it moves from point to point. I am not using any physics engine, and am not seeking any solution dealing with collisions, but I would like the ball to correctly demonstrate what would be happening if the movement were due to the ball rolling down a track.

So, to make a little more clear the challenge, let's say that the ball is a billiard ball with the stripe and label for #15. In that case, the visual result should be that the number 15 should be turning head over heals, but, as you can probably surmise from the name of my **obj.moveTo()** function, that only results in changes in position of the 3D object, not its orientation.

That, finally, brings me to the specific question/request. I have been unable to discover what rotation changes must be synchronized with each positional change in order to correctly demonstrate the way the billiard ball would appear if it rolled from point 1 from point 2 along the path.

Part of the solution appears to be:

```
obj.setRotation ((Math.atan2 (Math.sin (ft), Math.cos (ft))), Vector3D.Y_AXIS);
```

but that is still not correct. I hope there is some well-known formula that I can add to my render code.

Comment: you should rotate the ball by ah amount equal to distance traveled (so you have to convert arc=>radians). the axis of rotation is perpendicular to the plane designed by normal Helix axis and motion direction (or at least should be a good looking approx

Comment: I had forgotten about my posting thiw question.  What a joy to finally have a response and a very helpful one indeed.  Thank you.